# Spring boot gradle project in Docker with continuous build

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, dockerfile

I've created a **spring starter** project with **gradle** as dependency manager and also including **spring-boot-dev-tools**. My aim is to create a docker image so that there must be **live reload** whenever I change a java file inside docker container. This is working well with following configurations.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gradle:5.6.2-jdk8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN gradle build
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["sh", "start.sh"]
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
gradle --version
gradle build --continuous &
gradle bootRun
```

**This is working**

One of my controller file is as follows.

```
@RestController
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    String test() {
        return "Test Success";
    }
}
```

Getting "Test Success" in browser when navigating to `localhost:8080`. When the file `/app/.../MainController.java` inside docker container is changed to say, `return "Updated";`, the change is affected automatically.

**This is the issue**

Even if there is `RUN gradle build` inside Dockerfile, `docker run` command with this image seems to be **downloading the gradle dependencies again** because of the command `gradle build --continuous` or `gradle bootRun`.

I want the `docker run` command fast, like it's downloaded all the dependencies already. Please suggest a workaround. Live reload is needed.

Comment: Have you tried mapping your ~/.gradle folder from your host machine to /root/.gradle in the container ?

Comment: @JonathP Thanks for your support. I'd resolved the issue, but forgot to post the answer. By mapping gradle dependencies from host machine, a dependency to host will be created there and the Docker image won't be able to run in a host machine without gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `getDeps` option inside the Dockerfile and `skipDownload` in start.sh file. This will download all the dependencies during Docker build and the live reload is now fast.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM gradle:5.6.2-jdk8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN gradle --no-daemon --warning-mode all --console=plain getDeps

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["sh", "start.sh"]
```

**start.sh file**

```
#!/bin/bash
gradle --version
gradle build --continuous -PskipDownload=true --console=plain &
gradle bootRun -PskipDownload=true --console=plain
```

**build.gradle**

```
// other configs
ext {
    skipDownload = project.hasProperty('skipDownload') ? project.getProperty('skipDownload') as boolean : false
}    
repositories {
    if (skipDownload) {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    } else {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencies {
    if (skipDownload) {
        implementation files('libs/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc-2.3.7.RELEASE.jar')

    } else {
        implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc', version: '2.3.7.RELEASE'

    }
}
task getDeps(type: Copy) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from configurations.compileClasspath into "libs/"
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath into "libs/"
}
```

Comment: Where is getDeps? Also, how do you deal with local Gradle dependencies? Do you run a Maven/Gradle repository service on-prem?

Comment: @ben3000 Please see the Dockerfile `RUN gradle ..... getDeps`. I don't understand the second question. What do you mean by local deps? This is a container and every build process happens inside the container (or intermediate container during docker build). So all we need to do is to create the image from a base gradle image - `FROM gradle:5.6.2-jdk8`.

Comment: Again I had another problem with this setup and improved it further. Please see this for details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663235/spring-boot-live-reload-inside-a-docker-container-not-working

Comment: Is `getDeps` a gradle task that you've developed, or one provided by gradle? By local dependencies, I mean libraries that I have built that I [manually publish to Maven local](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html), is there a way to handle this?

Comment: @ben3000 I've updated the Answer with relevant gradle settings. Thanks for pointing this out.